# GridVIew does not refresh after paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

My `GridView` is populated with a certain filter criteria.

I have `PageIndexChanging` event to perform pagination of my data.

```
protected void gvPeople_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    lblAddError.Text = String.Empty;
    List<People> list = (List<People>)ViewState[_vsPeopleList];
    gvPeople.DataSource = list;
    gvPeople.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvPeople.EditIndex = -1;
    gvPeople.DataBind();
}
```

After that I perfrom `Search` without changing the filter criteria.

```
protected void btnPeopleSearch_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName.Equals("Search"))
    {
        PopulatePeople();
    }
}

private void PopulatePeople()
{
    lblAddError.Text = String.Empty;
    if (ViewState["_message"] != null)
    {
        lblAddError.Visible = true;
        lblAddError.Text = ViewState["_message"].ToString();
    }
    ViewState["_message"] = null;

    int portfolio = int.Parse(ddlPortfolio.SelectedItem.Value);
    ViewState["portfolioID"] = portfolio;
    string year = ddlYear.SelectedItem.Text;
    string month = ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text;

    List<People> list = People.GetPeople(portfolio, year, month);
    ViewState[_vsPeopleList] = list;
    if(list.Count == 0)
    {
        gvPeople.Visible = false;
        lblAddError.Visible = true;
        lblAddError.Text = "No data available for current selection";
    }
    else
    {
        gvPeople.Visible = true;
        gvPeople.DataSource = list;
        gvPeople.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to get all the data in the `GridView` as I had before paging to the next page. However, my page does not refresh to show all the data, it only shows the data for that page index, however, my list has count equals to the number of records populated from the database. Also, if I change search filter, data is displayed correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the gvHolidays_PageIndexChanging event is related to some other grid as the code written within it is for grid gvPeople.

If not, then try the following.

```
//Write the following code inside gridviews PageIndexChanging event.
gvPeople.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
gvPeople.EditIndex = -1;
gvPeople.SelectedIndex = -1;

//Write the following code inside gvHolidays_PageIndexChanged event.
lblAddError.Text = String.Empty;
List<People> list = (List<People>)ViewState[_vsPeopleList];
gvPeople.DataSource = list;
gvPeople.DataBind();
```

Comment: Still the same problem